# Accessing the j-th element in every row of a 2D numpy array via colon operator?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a 2D numpy array `a`, I can access the j-th element in every row like this:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
>>> j = np.array([0,1,0])
>>> j
array([0, 1, 0])
>>> i = np.arange(3)
>>> i
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> a[i,j] = 1
>>> a
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

However, I would have expected that by accessing the rows via the colon operator results in the same:

```py
>>> b = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> b[:,j] = 1
>>> b
array([[1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0.]])
```

Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour as shown in the first example by using the colon operators?
How would I need to alter the array `j`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are looking to use a colon only? I am not aware of such way to access the elements the way you like it with colon

Comment: `a[i,j]` is roughly equivalent to `[a[x,y] for x,y in zip(i,j)]`,   It's pairing elements of `i` and `j` (via `broadcasting`).  `a[:,j]` means take all rows (the slice), and the `j` columns.  There's nothing like that list/array broadcasting.

Comment: @Ehsan: The reason is just to deepen my understanding of numpy. My proposed method is just fine from a functional perspective.

Comment: There's a lot of read and understand on this `indexing` page, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html